# Reordering MySQL rows based on a certain row

Tags: mysql, push

I have a table in MySQL and this table contains the information of the adverts in my website. In some cases, a row need to go on top of query result to be shown first in the page and this might be needed for some other rows frequently. I'm looking for a proper way to push up a specific row to the top of the query result.

What is the best solution to accomplish this task?

Comment: Usually either `ORDER BY` with complicated conditions, or combine two queries. What are the conditions like?

Comment: If you will not provide query &|or data its difficult to answer.

Comment: `order by case when condition =1 and Othercondition = 2 then 1 else condition 2 end, Field2, Field3, Field4`  This way those meeting your condition(s) are 1st.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let assume your special row has a field like `SpecialAd`

```
 SELECT *
 FROM YourTable
 ORDER BY CASE 
              WHEN `SpecialAd` = true THEN 0
                                      ELSE 1
          END,
          OtherSortField
```

with this all SpecialAd will be show first, and you can use the second SortField to sort inside each group.